# update table row from another row same table

Tags: mysql, copy, row

[table image with columns and rows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL7sd.jpg)

hello, i want to update all rows with language_code = ro to be the same with the one with language_code=en ( only name, meta_description, short_description, description and head_title) i have tried

```
UPDATE lc_products_info lc LEFT JOIN lc_products_info lc2 ON (lc.product_id=lc2.product_id AND lc.name='' AND lc2.language_code='en') SET lc.name = lc2.name;
```

but it seems to delete the content of rows with leanguage code = en if any one can help me....thanks in advance

Comment: use some where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Where`:

```
UPDATE lc_products_info lc
LEFT JOIN lc_products_info lc2 ON lc.product_id=lc2.product_id AND lc2.language_code='en' SET lc.name = lc2.name
WHERE lc.name=''
AND lc.language_code='ro';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE lc SET name=lc2.name FROM lc_products_info lc LEFT JOIN lc_products_info lc2 ON lc.product_id=lc2.product_id AND lc.name='' AND lc2.language_code='en'
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.